# How to define separate hidden props for GET and POST methods in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want some props to be visible for GET method in loopback explorer, but I don't want to show them for POST method, for e.g. `id` property. How it can be done in loopback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in methods for this.

You need to do it in after remote for each remote method you want to be different from the default.

```
Model.afterRemote('GetMethod', function(ctx, instance, next){
  var instance = ctx.result;
  //reshape it
  ctx.result = instance;
  next();
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to affect this in explorer component so you need to create separate models with `null` datasource just for showing schema and use that in definition of remote method.

```
Model.remoteMethod('GetMethod', {
    accepts: [
      {
        arg: 'req',
        type: 'Object',
        required: true,
        http: {source: 'req'}
      }
    ],
    returns: {root: true, type: 'ModelDTOForSHow'},
    http: {verb: 'get', status: 200, path: '/getter'}
  });
```

And in `ModelDTOForShow` you hide some props and in another one some other props

Comment: will it affect the definitions in loopback explorer as well?

Comment: @YuriyChachora No it doesn't

Comment: my idea was to have separate definitions for explorer as well